# Testing internal classes in swift framework

Tags: swift, unit-testing, frameworks

I did not find a way to unit test an internal swift class that is inside a framework. It only works if I set the class scope to public. Is there a way around it ?

Here is what I have now:

**In the framework:**

```
class InternalClass {}
```

**In the tests:**

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyFramework
class InternalClassTests: XCTestCase {
  let sut = InternalClass() //ERROR HERE Use of unresolved identifier 'InternalClass'
}
```

Comment: check your `InternalClass` file's `target membership` and make sure it available for your testing target too

Comment: Yes of course, I do not know how I forgot this part...  Thank you very much ! @QuocNguyen

Comment: @QuocNguyen could you please post your comment as an answer? therefore I will be able to mark it as solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your `InternalClass` as internal class, you must add your `InternalClass` to your `UnitTest` target.

You can simple do it by click to the checkbox of the Unit Test target, in the file's `Target Membership`. (select your file and find it in the `Inspectors` bar)

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't add the `IntenalClass` to both main target and `unitTest` target cause symbol conflict?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@testable` before your framework import in your unit test file like

`@testable import MyFramework`

which give you access to at least your `internal` method and classes in your framework.